# How to assign enum variable to a pointer of array index

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, enums

Say I have `enum unit{ var1, var2, var3};`
Then I have an array in the main function

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]);
```

I want to assign `argv[1]` to `var1`, where `argv[1]` was input through command line, I m not sure how to go about doing this for pointer of array. I know how to get the input from command line but trouble assigning it to `var1`.

Comment: Try doing `char *var1 = argv[1];`

Comment: I got an error "ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code" and "unused variable 'var1'"

Comment: `argv[i]` is a pointer to a string, while `var1` is an integer value defined via an enum. That cannot match. Please describe more detailled what you try to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Enum values must be known at compile time, but `argv` is only known at run time.

Comment: What do you suggest I do? Should I initialise all var1,2,3 to say =1 then change them through the same process. Would it still be possible then?

Comment: @Emily - struct is another option here. Is it necessary to use enums ?

Comment: @Rizwan Yes because its part of a project and it seems to me I must store these values in enum, I cant change what the project asks me to do. Some startup code has these vars already in the enum.

Comment: @Emily -  if you want to store, modify and use a logical group of values. struct is the answer. Enum needs to be defined at compile times only, can't be modified later. Enum can only be used to get values later on.

Comment: @Rizwan Yes thats correct I wont need to modify these var1,2,3 at all. I would only need the value for later reference. How can I do what I asked?

Comment: I don't understand what you need to do. What do you mean with "need the value for later reference"? You need to describe your problem more clearly, and maybe  give a concrete example (in the question).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the values of `enum` at run-time, `structs` are the best implementation here, I advise you change your code to this;

```
struct unit{ var1, var2, var3};
```

Then you can use a pointer to manipulate the values.